# Proof for A majorizes B

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\alpha = [\alpha_i] \in\mathbb R^n$ and $\beta = [\beta_i]$ where $\beta_1 = \beta_2 = ......=\beta_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum\alpha_i$

How can i show that $\alpha$ majorizes $\beta$

I tried to get a start by considering that as all enteries of $\beta_i$ are same, so definitely i dont need to reorder them. But should i reorder $\alpha_i$ is increasing or decreasing order?

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the definition of majorization that $\alpha$ should be reordered in decreasing order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, for a given n-dimensional vectors of $\alpha=[\alpha_i]$ and $\beta=[\beta_i]$, $\alpha_1\leq\alpha_2\leq\cdots\leq\alpha_n$ and $\beta_1\leq\beta_2\leq\cdots\leq\beta_n$, $\alpha$ majorizes $\beta$ if
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i=\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\leq\sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i \quad \text{for $k=1,\cdots,n$}.
\end{equation*}
So, 
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i=n(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i
\end{equation*}
which satisfies the first condition. additionally
\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i=k(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i).
\end{equation*}
Since $k\leq n$ then $\frac{k}{n}\leq 1$, moreover, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ elements are sorted in increasing order, therefore we have
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\leq \frac{k}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i.
\end{equation}
which satisfies the second condition.

Comment: how can one see that $\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\leq \frac{k}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i.$ holds?